# js api no extended permissions after initial login

Tags: javascript, api, permissions, facebook-login

I am trying to set a permission with in my app to request a users email.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'APP_ID',
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    oauth      : true,
  });
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    //window.location.reload();
    window.location = "/welcome.html";
  });

};


(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email" >
    Login with Facebook
</div>
```

When a user is currently logged into facebook, they are presented with a dialog asking them to allow my app. It also asks for permission to use their email. This is the expected behavior, and works.

When a user is currently NOT logged into facebook, they are presented with a login dialog (this is also expected, and works) the next dialog that appears is one to allow my app, but it DOES NOT have the permission for their email, and this is where I am having trouble.

I have read and tried various methods that are described in other questions. Like calling the FB.login method with an onclick and setting the permission scope that way, and still no luck.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     window.location = "/welcome.html";  
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

I know this is possible as I've seen several other apps do this properly, I just cant see what I'm missing. I've also tried the xfbml approach and had the same issue as with the div.

Comment: Ok so this odd, I went to test this code again this morning and it works as expected, with out any changes. I'm not sure what was happening. I was logged out of fb, then logged in via my app, then approved my app and it was showing the email permission.Gremlins somewhere I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with subscribing to that `auth.login` event.  It is even called when the SDK performs a login check when it sees `status : true` in the `FB.init()`.

Notice what I do with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/R4g47/ (it's commented out, but you and uncomment it and run the script.  You can see you want to pay attention to the status being sent to that.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    // {
    //   status: "",         /* Current status of the session */
    //   authResponse: {          /* Information about the current session */
    //      userID: ""          /* String representing the current user's ID */
    //      signedRequest: "",  /* String with the current signedRequest */
    //      expiresIn: "",      /* UNIX time when the session expires */
    //      accessToken: "",    /* Access token of the user */
    //   }
    // }

    alert('event status: ' + response.status);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, Guess there is more then one way to skin this cat :)

Comment: Yes, there are many.  Stick with one way and get it debugged.  That's the best plan of attack.